# compiling ffmpeg with fixed arguments?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compile, arguments

I would like to compile ffmpeg with fixed arguments, ie:
ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost/live -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://remotehost/live

I can't for security reasons call it from an external script, this must be included in
the ffmpeg binary. Prblem is that the source codes are very big , so do u know a simple
way to do that ?

Tx

Comment: why my questions is disabled ?  is this not computing ?

Comment: I think this is actually on topic. But it really seems like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). If you can run a random binary (which you compiled) on a system it does not make sense that you cannot control its arguments.